# How to validate exact value of "true" and "false" accurately in Java using regular expression?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to give **success** as output only if the user gives the input as true or false. Anything other than that should show **error**. I have used Regex in order to do that. But some of the scenarios are not getting validated as per the requirement.

I have used Regex to check if the acceptance value given by the user is true or false. Anything other than true or false should show an error. If the user gives null value then also it should show error.
My code -
``

```
...
public static Boolean isValidAcceptanceField(String acceptanceValue){
Boolean flag= false;
if(acceptanceValue!=null && (acceptanceValue.matches(".*true.*") || acceptanceValue.matches(".*false*."))){
 flag=true;
}
return flag;
}`
....
```

a)This code is validating perfectly the following scenarios-

```
acceptanceValue    Output
null               error
trrrrue            error
truuuuue           error
peter              error
faaalse            error
falllse            error
fal#se             error
```

Here for the scenarios written in a) section the requirement is to get "success" as output and it is working fine.

b)This code is not validating the following scenarios-

```
acceptanceValue    Output
tttrue             Success
trueeee            Success
ffffalse           Success
falseee            Success
true#              Success
```

Here for the scenarios written in b) section the requirement is get "error" as output but it is giving success.So is not working fine.

It seems like the code is not validating the value if the typing mistake is being done at the beginning or the end of the acceptance field.
What Regex should I use to validate true and false perfectly in all the scenarios?

Comment: Regex is needlessly complicated for such a simple case. a Simple `return "true".equals(acceptanceValue) || "false".equals(acceptanceValue);` is really all you need.

Comment: In fact, regex failed you here, as `.*true.*` would match _anything_ containing `true`, not equaling it. Your regex for an exact match would end up as `"true"`, which at that point you could simply compare the strings.

Comment: I can't change the acceptanceValue field as Boolean. It should be a String.

Comment: @GeekToLearn I don't get what you are trying to say with that comment. No one ever suggested you change the type of that field. We simply suggested you do a simple String comparison via equals, which has nothing to do with changing the type of your method argument.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by OH GOD SPIDERS, the following is a complete, correct, and compiling implementation of the method you want.

```
public static Boolean isValidAcceptanceField(String acceptanceValue){
  return acceptanceValue.equals("true") || acceptanceValue.equals("false");
}
```

(This version throws on null, as it should.)

Comment: Why it should throw NPE on null? Why not use `"true".equals(acceptanceValue)` instead without any possibility for NPE? Null != true and Null != false so method should return false